# Read cvs file to Dictionary python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Please, I need to read CSV file and convert the result to a dictionary.

File input:

[image]

The required object after reading like below:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {‘Book’: {‘Book’: 1.0, ‘Afnan’: 0, ‘Location’: 0, ‘Love’: 0}, ‘Afnan’: {‘Book’: 0, ‘Afnan’: 1.0, ‘Location’: 0.71, ‘Love’: 0}, ‘Location’: {‘Book’: 0, 'Afnan’: 0.71, ‘Location’: 1.0, ‘Love’: 0}, ‘Love’: {‘Book’: 0, ‘Afnan’: 0, ‘Location’: 0, ‘Love’: 1.0}})
```

I write below code but is not working as what I want. Please help.

```
reader = unicode_csv_reader(open('cos3.csv'))
x=list(reader)
for i in x:
    if isinstance(i,float):
        arr=np.array(x).astype('float')
    else:
        arr=np.array(x).astype('string')
d=defaultdict(dict)
for a in arr:
    for b in arr:
        d[a][b]=arr(a)
```

Comment: The image of a spreadsheet is **not** a correct representation for a csv file. It does not show the delimiters nor the eventual quotes, and on the opposite it could let think that the name of the sheet (here Table 1) is inside the file. Next time, please show what a text editor (notepad, vi, etc.) would show.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `csv.DictReader` and then build the dictionary in the format you want like so:

[image]

```
import csv
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()


d_out = {}
with open(cwd+'\\example.csv', 'rb') as file_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_in, restkey=None, restval=None, dialect='excel')
    for row in reader:
        d_out.setdefault(row['Key'], {'Book':row['Book'], 'Afnan':row['Afnan'], 'Location':row['Location'], 'Love':row['Love']})


print d_out
```

Hope this helps!